# WebClient getting login page response on ASP.NET ASPX handler using Anonymous Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-8

I have an ASP.Net application configured to use anonymous authentication and it has an ".aspx" data handler page to process some RPC calls from WebClient objects. This worked fine when hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2, but now that I'm getting migrated to a new Windows Server 2012 server my WebClient queries never even reaches the server. Even if i disable the application in IIS I keep getting a corporate login page. If i send the request through a browser it works fine (when I have the application running). After looking at the request headers in the browser request, I found that if I added a cookie header to the WebClient object it works as intended.

```
client.Headers.Add("Cookie", "s_vi=[CS]v1|2A5F47608507C765-60000113A0063157[CE]; s_pers=%20s_vnum%3D1424366552113%2526vn%253D1%7C1424366552113%3B%20v44%3D%255B%255B%2527Direct%252520Load%2527%252C%25271421774552126%2527%255D%255D%7C1579540952126%3B%20s_pv%3Den_us%2520%253A%2520worldwide%2520%253A%2520global%2520landing%7C1421776386528%3B%20s_invisit%3Dtrue%7C1421776386530%3B%20s_lv%3D1421774586533%7C1516382586533%3B%20s_lv_s%3DFirst%2520Visit%7C1421776386533%3B%20s_cmc%3D1%7C1421776386540%3B%20s_nr%3D1426866016133-Repeat%7C1429458016133%3B%20s_fid%3D60E97348782318BD-305C723745392699%7C1490024416207%3B%20gpv_pn%3Ddivision%2520%253A%2520waterloo%2520works%2520%253A%2520home%7C1426867816209%3B; s_fid=22E0F07165D84047-07AD087FC8A8DC6F; s_nr=1477321997125-Repeat; SMSESSION=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; gpv_pn=division%20%3A%20waterloo%20works%20%3A%20home; s_cc=true");
```

I have a feeling this cookie is using my credentials to let this WebClient access this new server, which is not how I intended it to be configured. Is the server configured badly somehow to not allow anonymous access?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this because the server is protected by SiteMinder. I'll have to find a work around that allows for an authenticated request to be accepted by my site, but it's beyond the scope of this question.